# Creating cascading Heading tags with CSS sibling selectors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to create better flow of my headers, by indenting them a small amount depending on what the parent is. For example H1 no indent, if H2 follows H1, then indent 1, else no... if H3 follows H1/H2 then indent, etc. so it cascades the indents appropriately. Further it would cool if I could indent the content/p after every header tag... I have tried the following CSS after a bunch of research...

```
h1 {margin-left:0em;}
h1 ~ *:not(h1) {margin-left: 1em;}
h2 ~ *:not(h2) {{margin-left: 2em;}
```

Unfortunately this loses it's reach when another H1 is added... notice the following

```
Heading 1
    Heading 2.1
        Paragraph 2.1.1
        Paragraph 2.1.2
        Paragraph 2.1.3
    Heading 2.2
        Paragraph 2.2.1
        Paragraph 2.2.2
        Paragraph 2.2.3
        Heading 1.2 <this is wrong???
    Heading 2.1
        Paragraph 2.1.1
        Paragraph 2.1.2
        Paragraph 2.1.3
    Heading 2.2
        Paragraph 2.2.1
        Paragraph 2.2.2
        Paragraph 2.2.3
```

I want to try to do this without JS and only us CSS, is this possible?

Comment: You probably need `+` more than `~`. It's the ['adjacent sibling' selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors).

Comment: is this a copy/paste error : h2 ~ *:not(h2) **{** {margin-left: 2em;} ?

Comment: Sounds like you just need standard left padding on your `h2`s and `p`s. 'Parent' is not the right word in this situation, as the following elements are not inside the h1s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I honestly don't entirely understand why you want to do this.  It seems cleaner to just always indent `h2` elements.  But I'll assume you have your reasons.  You can fix this by making the `h1` selector more specific than the other selector so that it takes precedence:

```
html body h1 {margin-left:0em;color: red;}
h1 ~ *:not(h1) {margin-left: 1em;color: blue;}
h2 ~ *:not(h2) {margin-left: 2em;color: green}
```

In this way, even though the 2nd `h1` matches both the first and 3rd selectors, the first now takes precedence since it is more specific.

http://jsfiddle.net/LUPD5/

Comment: Thanks that worked pretty good. It's mostly for the content following... For example, I don't have to create h2 p div etc for all other things... it's a global way to set the H1 cascade... I wonder if there is a way to actually set it so that the indent is relative like +1em, not absolute?

Comment: If you feel dirty using a specificity hack, you can explicitly target that `h1` using `h1, h2 ~ h1` and move the first ruleset to the bottom.

Comment: @BoltClock  ooh hack is such a harsh word, hah.  I tend to favor specificity because then order doesn't matter.